# visualizing id, x, y, t data

Tags: python, animation, visualization

I have the following vehicle data

```
vehicle_id, position_x, position_y, time
```

The data represents the position of a vehicle at time 't' . The data is also available as a linear reference. I was wondering what's a simple way to visualize the vehicle movement as an animation? I would prefer a solution that I can integrate with python

**EDIT**
The animation I plan on doing should be similar to the 2d one found in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL6JDtnCH_s)

Comment: How necessary is it that this visualization be animated?  Animation is neat, but seeing all the data for a particular vehicle at once is more informative.

Comment: @las3rjock it is important since i'm visualizing a small number of vehicles in an intersection, it's based on some monte carlo simulation, and logit data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of animation did you have in mind? You can try [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org) for desktop app. They have a nice tutorial about [this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine its best done on a map; consider integrating (Google) maps with a custom path representing the vehicle.

Comment: are you aware of how i can do it as an animation?

Comment: I wasn't, so I used Google... and there were tons of discussion and examples.

Comment: cool i'll try it out, but i much prefer someone I can integrate with my app, and independent of Google

Answer (score 2):

Use pygame for it.